# Session in Silverlight Enabled Web Service

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf

I have created a Silverlight enabled WCF Service which looks like :
I am using basicHttpBinding

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SLWebService
    {


        [OperationContract]
        public string Login(string username, string password)
        {
            //Validate Username and Password against the Database.
           // myctxt.Session["Uname"] = username;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = username ;
            return username;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        public string ReturnUser()
        {
            return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["username"];
        }

    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is i am getting username value is null everytime.
I am consuming this WCF Service in Silverlight Client which looks like :

Page.xaml.cs:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SessionService.SLWebServiceClient client = new SessionService.SLWebServiceClient();
            client.LoginAsync(txtuser.Text, txtpassword.Password);    
            NavigateRequest(1); 

        }
```

Welcome.xaml.cs

```
void Welcome_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SessionService.SLWebServiceClient client = new SessionService.SLWebServiceClient();
            client.ReturnUserCompleted += new EventHandler<SessionService.ReturnUserCompletedEventArgs>(client_ReturnUserCompleted);
            client.ReturnUserAsync(); 
        }

        void client_ReturnUserCompleted(object sender, SessionService.ReturnUserCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtusername.Text = e.Result; 
        }
```

I am creating a Login Page(Page.xaml) ans entering Userid and password then it redirects to Welcome Page which welcome the current user but my service is not returning the username the session is null.

Thanks.

Comment: Some body help please urgently

Comment: Did you debug the service? Is the incoming parameter correct?

Comment: @Erno : U mean to say username parameter ? yes i debug the service and for the first time session is null now when i refresh the page i get the value, but for the first time session is null only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]` above " public class SLWebService"